# WSDL validation in Eclipse fails for namespace

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, soap, wsdl

I've made a WSDL file and I intend to create top down web service out of it. Unfortunately, Eclipse throws this error:

`"A problem occurred while running the WSDL validator for namespace http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"`

I've made some research and it looks like it's happening because of some Eclipse wsdl-validation bug, explained [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=323157)

Some guy there claims that he fixed this error with patch, and I've applied it, but the error stays and I'm starting to think that there's some problem with my wsdl file itself.

WebService is supposed to take a list(column) of ID's and return a 2-column table data based on those ID's.

Can you help me find out what is wrong with it?

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2) 
Build id: 20160218-0600 
WTP 1.2.1.20150819-2220

Here's WSDL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions 
  targetNamespace="reb.ecm.ws.RebUtilsService"
        xmlns="reb.ecm.ws.RebUtilsService"
        xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
        xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
        xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">


    <wsdl:types>
      <xsd:complexType name='DPList'>
        <xsd:element
          minOccurs='0'
          maxOccurs='unbounded'
          name='DP'
          type='DP'/>
      </xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:complexType name='DP'>
        <xsd:all>
          <xsd:element
            minOccurs='0'
            maxOccurs='1'
            name='DPID'
            type='xsd:int'/>
        </xsd:all>
      </xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:complexType name='WSInfoList'>
        <xsd:element
          minOccurs='0'
          maxOccurs='unbounded'
          name='WSInfoItem'
          type='WSInfoItem'/>
      </xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:complexType name='WSInfoItem'>
        <xsd:all>
          <xsd:element
            minOccurs='0'
            maxOccurs='1'
            name='DPID'
            type='xsd:int'/>
        </xsd:all>
        <xsd:all>
          <xsd:element
            minOccurs='0'
            maxOccurs='1'
            name='WSID'
            type='xsd:int'/>
        </xsd:all>
      </xsd:complexType>
    </wsdl:types>

    <wsdl:message name="inMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="DPList" type="DPList" />
    </wsdl:message>

    <wsdl:message name="outMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="WSInfoList" type="WSInfoList" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="RebUtilsServicePortType">
        <wsdl:operation name="GetActualWSIDbyDPID"  >
            <wsdl:input message="inMessage" />
            <wsdl:output message="outMessage" />
        </wsdl:operation>
                    </wsdl:portType>

    <wsdl:binding name="RebUtilsServiceHTTPBinding" 
            type="RebUtilsServicePortType">
        <wsdlsoap:binding style="document" 
            transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetActualWSIDbyDPID">
            <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>
             <wsdl:input>
                <wsdlsoap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <wsdlsoap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>

    <wsdl:service name="RebUtilsServicePorts">
        <wsdl:port binding="RebUtilsServiceHTTPBinding"  name="RebUtilsService">
            <wsdlsoap:address 
                location="http://localhost:9084/RebUtilsService/RebUtilsServicePorts"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>

</wsdl:definitions>
```

UPDATE: There were no problem with Eclipse. At least patch, mentioned earlier fixed something.

Comment: Can you please let know which version of eclipse you are using? Also please install Eclipse WSDL Validation plugin from Eclipse Marketplace and try to regenerate your client code?

Comment: Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)
Build id: 20160218-0600


WTP 1.2.1.20150819-2220

Comment: Can you post a link to WSDL walidation plugin, cause I'm having trouble running Eclipse marketplace beacause of proxy settings in my organization.

Comment: Shows some errors in your schema definition, can you please post your schema?

Comment: There is no schema, I've typed everything I need into <wsdl:types>. I thought that it is sufficient as it is.

Comment: it requires schema to be mapped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer**

1. Your schema is not properly defined. Please see the below image.
   [image: datatypeError]
2. Kindly change it to your corrected datatype element which is defined in your schema definitions, Please change in Eclipse WSDL Design view.
   [image: correctedSchema]
3. Regenerate your client and let know the results.
4. You should have seperate XSD schema files and should be mapped based on your requirement, that's why it is failing and please have a look into the exploded design view.[image: schema mapping]

**General Rule**

5. While creating a SOAP Service, Please define your required input/output XSD schemas
6. Using schema as in input you need to generate the WSDL file using your IDE/Maven/any build tool.
7. For easier manipulations/Edits, please choose Eclipse WSDL Editor.